# Is there a way to run a foreach() on a sorted result set in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My goal is to copy every item in collection 1 to collection 2 in order of "page_length" descending, such that the new collection has the largest page_length field first, second is the second largest and so on.

I tried the following in Mongo:

```
db.mycollection1.find().sort({page_length:-1}).foreach(function(d) { db.mycollection2.insert({"field1":d.field1, "field2":d.field2}); })
```

Got an error that DBQuery has no method 'foreach'. I know that foreach() is a function of find() but I was hoping to find a workaround. I even tried the following:

```
db.mycollection1.aggregate({$sort:{page_length:-1}}).foreach(function(d) { db.mycollection2.insert({"field1":d.field1, "field2":d.field2}); })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your first example is correct except that you have `foreach` instead of `forEach`. It needs the upper case `E`.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
db.mycollection1.find().sort().forEach(function(e) { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort first here I have sort with Last Name of Customer try below query

> db.customers.find().sort({lastname:1}).forEach(function(doc){print("Customer  name:"+doc.lastname)});